# How to Hash CPU ID in C

Tags: c, hash, embedded, compression, hashids

I'm trying to short the cpu id of my microcontroller (STM32F1).

The cpu id is composed by 3 word ( 3 x 4 bytes). This is the id string built from the 3 word: `980416578761680031125348904`

I found a very useful library that do this.

The library is [Hashids](http://hashids.org/c/) and there is a C code.

I try to build a test code on PC with "Code Blocks IDE" and the code works.

But when I move the code into the embedded side (Keil v5 IDE), I get an error on strdup() function: "strdup implicit declaration of function".

The problem is related to the strdup function isn't a standard library function and ins't included into string.h.

I will avoid to replace the strdup function with a custom function (that mimic the behaviour of strdup) to avoid memory leak because strdup copy strings using malloc.

Is there a different approach to compress long numbers?

Thanks for the help!

<---Appendix--->

This is the function that uses the strdup.

```
    /* common init */
    struct hashids_t *
    hashids_init3(const char *salt, size_t min_hash_length, const char *alphabet)
    {
    struct hashids_t *result;
    unsigned int i, j;
    size_t len;
    char ch, *p;

    hashids_errno = HASHIDS_ERROR_OK;

    /* allocate the structure */
    result = _hashids_alloc(sizeof(struct hashids_t));
    if (HASHIDS_UNLIKELY(!result)) {
        hashids_errno = HASHIDS_ERROR_ALLOC;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* allocate enough space for the alphabet and its copies */
    len = strlen(alphabet) + 1;
    result->alphabet = _hashids_alloc(len);
    result->alphabet_copy_1 = _hashids_alloc(len);
    result->alphabet_copy_2 = _hashids_alloc(len);
    if (HASHIDS_UNLIKELY(!result->alphabet || !result->alphabet_copy_1
        || !result->alphabet_copy_2)) {
        hashids_free(result);
        hashids_errno = HASHIDS_ERROR_ALLOC;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* extract only the unique characters */
    result->alphabet[0] = '\0';
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        ch = alphabet[i];
        if (!strchr(result->alphabet, ch)) {
            result->alphabet[j++] = ch;
        }
    }
    result->alphabet[j] = '\0';

    /* store alphabet length */
    result->alphabet_length = j;

    /* check length and whitespace */
    if (result->alphabet_length < HASHIDS_MIN_ALPHABET_LENGTH) {
        hashids_free(result);
        hashids_errno = HASHIDS_ERROR_ALPHABET_LENGTH;
        return NULL;
    }
    if (strchr(result->alphabet, ' ')) {
        hashids_free(result);
        hashids_errno = HASHIDS_ERROR_ALPHABET_SPACE;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* copy salt */
    result->salt = strdup(salt ? salt : HASHIDS_DEFAULT_SALT);
    result->salt_length = (unsigned int) strlen(result->salt);

    /* allocate enough space for separators */
    result->separators = _hashids_alloc((size_t)
        (ceil((float)result->alphabet_length / HASHIDS_SEPARATOR_DIVISOR) + 1));
    if (HASHIDS_UNLIKELY(!result->separators)) {
        hashids_free(result);
        hashids_errno = HASHIDS_ERROR_ALLOC;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* non-alphabet characters cannot be separators */
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen(HASHIDS_DEFAULT_SEPARATORS); ++i) {
        ch = HASHIDS_DEFAULT_SEPARATORS[i];
        if ((p = strchr(result->alphabet, ch))) {
            result->separators[j++] = ch;

            /* also remove separators from alphabet */
            memmove(p, p + 1,
                strlen(result->alphabet) - (p - result->alphabet));
        }
    }

    /* store separators length */
    result->separators_count = j;

    /* subtract separators count from alphabet length */
    result->alphabet_length -= result->separators_count;

    /* shuffle the separators */
    hashids_shuffle(result->separators, result->separators_count,
        result->salt, result->salt_length);

    /* check if we have any/enough separators */
    if (!result->separators_count
        || (((float)result->alphabet_length / (float)result->separators_count)
                > HASHIDS_SEPARATOR_DIVISOR)) {
        unsigned int separators_count = (unsigned int)ceil(
            (float)result->alphabet_length / HASHIDS_SEPARATOR_DIVISOR);

        if (separators_count == 1) {
            separators_count = 2;
        }

        if (separators_count > result->separators_count) {
            /* we need more separators - get some from alphabet */
            int diff = separators_count - result->separators_count;
            strncat(result->separators, result->alphabet, diff);
            memmove(result->alphabet, result->alphabet + diff,
                result->alphabet_length - diff + 1);

            result->separators_count += diff;
            result->alphabet_length -= diff;
        } else {
            /* we have more than enough - truncate */
            result->separators[separators_count] = '\0';
            result->separators_count = separators_count;
        }
    }

    /* shuffle alphabet */
    hashids_shuffle(result->alphabet, result->alphabet_length,
        result->salt, result->salt_length);

    /* allocate guards */
    result->guards_count = (unsigned int) ceil((float)result->alphabet_length
                                               / HASHIDS_GUARD_DIVISOR);
    result->guards = _hashids_alloc(result->guards_count + 1);
    if (HASHIDS_UNLIKELY(!result->guards)) {
        hashids_free(result);
        hashids_errno = HASHIDS_ERROR_ALLOC;
        return NULL;
    }

    if (HASHIDS_UNLIKELY(result->alphabet_length < 3)) {
        /* take some from separators */
        strncpy(result->guards, result->separators, result->guards_count);
        memmove(result->separators, result->separators + result->guards_count,
            result->separators_count - result->guards_count + 1);

        result->separators_count -= result->guards_count;
    } else {
        /* take them from alphabet */
        strncpy(result->guards, result->alphabet, result->guards_count);
        memmove(result->alphabet, result->alphabet + result->guards_count,
            result->alphabet_length - result->guards_count + 1);

        result->alphabet_length -= result->guards_count;
    }

    /* set min hash length */
    result->min_hash_length = min_hash_length;

    /* return result happily */
    return result;
}
```

Comment: can you post the code where `strdup` is used ?

Comment: *because strdup copy strings using malloc* - Why would this be an issue?

Comment: You can `strcpy()` a string into an automatic buffer array (or manually emulate such a `strcpy()`) if you want to avoid dynamic memory allocation.  This does require either support for VLAs, or advance knowledge of an upper bound on the size of the string you will copy.

Comment: please post a little more than the line with the strdup.

Comment: @AlexK. Because I don't understand the code inside Hashids lib and I don't want to replay a "standard function" with some code that uses dynamic memory. I can't tolerate memory leaks.

Comment: Is your CPU ID just a string representation of a decimal or hexadecimal number?  In that case, you can shrink it simply by converting to a numeric format.  A 12-digit decimal requires 40 bits.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: the cpu id is a decimal representation of the data contained into 3 32bit variable. I looking for something to compress the number. For example from a cpu id of 30 digit I would obtain a cpuid of 12 digits.

Comment: @Federico, if you don't understand the code you're looking at, then it seems unlikely  that you can modify it successfully.  Furthermore, you say you want a `strdup()` mimic that avoids `malloc()`, but that doesn't make sense -- dynamically allocating memory is one of the key characteristics of `strdup()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I know this. I don't want to build my own strdup, but I looking for a tested function that do this. I don't want to introduce some potential bug into my code.

Comment: @Federico, whether you write the code yourself or whether someone else writes it for you, a faithful `strdup()` mimic allocates memory dynamically.  That's part of its specification, and any trustworthy code using that function -- such as the hashing function you present -- chooses it in part for that purpose.  I think you've posed an XY question.

Comment: If you can't (don't want to) understand the code in Hashids lib how you can be sure that the lib itself is potentially bug free?

Comment: @Serge I cannot. But the library is widely used and has a big community of developers. this makes me think that the most common bugs have been eliminated

Comment: Anyway, what about calculating crc16, crc32 or adler32 over that 96bit data to make a hash of suitable for your purposes size?

Comment: @Serge: my pourpose is Identify the different embedded system on the field using the CPU Id. But to reduce the sent data, i need to short the cpu id. I need some algorithm that hash the  cpuId uniquely

Comment: @Federico: your requirements are inconsistent.  If your input has 96 significant, independent bits, then any conversion that outputs fewer than 96 bits does not produce unique results.

Comment: there is no way to loss-lessly compress 96bit of random data into something smaller unless you know some properties of that data, for example, you definitely  know that these bytes are always contains ASCII codes of hexadecimal digits. Otherwise, the only alternative is to make a hash that 1) will not allow you to recover the original ID and 2) will definitely have a collisions between different IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The true question seems to be

> Is there a different approach to compress long numbers?

There are many.  They differ in several respects, including which bits of the input contribute to the output, how many inputs map to the same output, and what manner of transformations of the input leave the output unchanged.

As a trivial examples, you can compress the input to a single bit by any of these approaches:

- Choose the lowest-order bit of the input
- Choose the highest-order bit of the input
- The output is always 1
- *etc*

Or you can compress to 7 bits by using using the number of 1 bits in the input as the output.

None of those particular options is likely to be of interest to you, of course.

Perhaps you would be more interested in producing 32-bit outputs for your 96-bit inputs.  ***Do note that in that case on average there will be at least 2<sup>64</sup> possible inputs that map to each possible output.***  That depends only on the sizes of input and output, not on any details of the conversion.

For example, suppose that you have

```
uint32_t *cpuid = ...;
```

pointing to the hardware CPU ID.  You can produce a 32-bit value from it that depends on all the bits of the input simply by doing this:

```
uint32_t cpuid32 = cpuid[0] ^ cpuid[1] ^ cpuid[2];
```

Whether that would suit your purpose depends on how you intend to use it.

Comment: Thanks John! You understand the problem! I think that 2^64 different output will be fine! My embedded systems on field will be much less.

Comment: @Federico you don't seem to understand the limitations here.  You will have 2^32 different outputs.  And 2^64 of the 96-bit strings will result in the exact same output.  In the xor (^) example, the cpuid32 of an ID with the same bit set in cpuid[0] and [1] and [2] will be the exact same as a different cpuid where they are all cleared...  As John noted above in the comments, if all 96 bits need to be unique, there is no way to compress...

Comment: As a note to go along with this, look at the STM32 reference manual for what fields go into the ID. Some of them are more useful than others, some won't change at all for a given part number. You should be able to pick a smaller subset of the 96 bits that will provide a majority of the uniqueness of the ID (things like X,Y position on wafer, wafer number, and lot number).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily implement `strdup` yourself like this:

```
char* strdup (const char* str)
{
  size_t size = strlen(str);
  char* result = malloc(size);  
  if(result != NULL)
  {
    memcpy(result, str, size+1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

That being said, using `malloc` or `strdup` on an embedded system is most likely just nonsense practice, [see this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171257/realloc-wasting-lots-of-space-in-my-mcu). Nor would you use float numbers. Overall, that library seems to have been written by a desktop-minded person.

If you are implementing something like for example a chained hash table on an embedded system, you would use a statically allocated memory pool and not `malloc`. I'd probably go with a non-chained one for that reason (upon duplicates, pick next free spot in the buffer).

Comment: OP said: "I will avoid to replace the strdup function with a custom function (that mimic the behaviour of strdup) to avoid memory leak because strdup copy strings using malloc."

Comment: I know he asked for a `strdup()` mimic, but he also says he wants to avoid dynamic memory allocation.  That leaves me uncertain what he *really* wants, but I don't think this is it.

Comment: This answer does point out that malloc probably does not make any sense at all to begin with.

Comment: The point is: I know that strdup require dynamic memory, but I want to build a not tested function that do this. Because I don't want to introduce bug into embedded system. By the way I don't know how the Hashids uses the dynamic memory just created.

Answer (score 0):

Unique device ID register (96 bits) is located under address 0x1FFFF7E8. It is factory programmed and is read-only. You can read it directly without using any other external library. For example:

```
unsigned int b = *(0x1FFFF7E8);
```

should give you the first 32 bits (31:0) of the unique device ID. If you want to retrieve a string as in case of the library mentioned, the following should work:

```
sprintf(id, "%08X%08X%08X", *(0x1FFFF7E8), *(0x1FFFF7E8 + 4), *(0x1FFFF7E8 + 8);
```

Some additional casting may be required, but generally that's what the library did. Please refer to STM32F1xx Reference Manual (RM0008), section 30.2 for more details. The exact memory location to read from is different in case of Cortex-M4 family of the MCUs.

Comment: I do exactly this. But the problem is not related to "How obtain the CPU Id", but "How to compress the Cpu ID digits".

Comment: Oh I got your question, sorry about the confusion. I'll leave my comment in case someone looked for it.